A padding issue when creating a navigation bar
I have just started HTML and CSS, and I want to make a navigation bar. I ran into a problem where each of my links has this weird padding under it when I hover over the links, as shown in pictures. Are there any ways to fix the issue without deleting the padding?


Browser: Microsoft Edge 126.0.2592.87


h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #131842;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #405D72;
}
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>



I was following this video and was expecting a similar result shown in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3uCSh6LIY0&t=232s
The navbar in the video:


Welcome to SO! On topic: you did not close your anchor <a> tagsat each line, like this:Home`

Don't forget to add your </a>closing tag. Here's a markup validator to let you check your future works - https://validator.w3.org/


h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #131842;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #405D72;
}
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




Your problem arises because you are not closing your <a> tags.
<nav> bars don't require <ul> and <li> tags ... just <a> tags. This will result in a simpler structure which is more robust and accessible. See this snippet.


nav {
  background-color: #131842;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #405D72;
}
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>




While it is pure technical correct that a nav does not require a list for the links it still should use it. Being more robust without it is technically incorrect. The main reason why you should do that is for accessibility reasons while even the W3C and WHATWG recommends it.

And yet it seems that the actual experience of users who use screen readers is that lists make their lives more difficult.

might be, but then it comes down to the accessibility rating which influences the SEO. While I agree that both have their pro and cons I find this statement somehow misleading and one-sided.

@tacoshy I can't find any reference that nav without ul affects accessibility score. I tested it with lighthouse and no warning or whatever show up. Any link ? (the W3C link uses it, however, it also says that it does not have to be this way)
